# Jquery date picker date format get variables separately

Tags: jquery

Hello everyone I'm trying to get variables separately from date picker with using date format. I want to get these variables date,month and year but how?

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.MM.yy' });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get date from datepicker you should use `$(".date").datepicker("getDate")`.

Code:

```
var date = $(".date").datepicker('getDate');
alert(date.getDate());         // Day of the month
alert(date.getMonth());        // Month with a zero index
alert(date.getDay());          // Day of the week
alert(date.getFullYear());     // The "full" year, e.g. 2011
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.date').datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd.MM.yy', 
        onSelect:function(text, ui){
            var dt=text.split('.');
            var d=dt[0]; m=dt[1]; y=dt[2];
            console.log(d); // day
            console.log(m); // month
            console.log(y);  // year
        }
    });
});​
```

Every time you select a date from the `datepicker` you will get your day, month and year in three separate variables.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/euzBz/1/).

**Update:**
Also remember, users can change/enter date directly from keyboard by typing so in this case you have to use `$('.date').on('change', function(){...})` to track the text box change event.

```
// textbox change
$('.date').on('change', function(){
    var dt=$(this).val();
    if(dt.match(/^(\d{2}).([a-zA-Z]+).(\d{4})$/))
    {
        var dt=dt.split('.');
        var d=dt[0]; m=dt[1]; y=dt[2];
        console.log(d);
        console.log(m);
        console.log(y);
    }
    else alert('Invalid date format !\n\nValid format example: 05.December.2012');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/euzBz/2/) (With Text Box change Event).